# Why won't my Modal open on a successful api call

Tags: axios, material-ui, modal-dialog

I designed a modal using Material UI that I am importing and passing props to. I'm trying to have the modal open in either the .then block or the .catch of the axios call. It opens in the .catch but not in the .then though I have other operations occurring without a problem in the .then block. Also all of the state is properly being set confirmed via console.log for the modal to open. If I remove the code from the .then block the modal opens fine.

This is just a snippet of the code. I removed all the other .then operations to make the code more simple. Any ideas would be appreciative.

```
import { ResponseModal } from "components/Modals/ApiResponse-Modal";

export const ImportDataProperties = ({ element }) => {  
    const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState("");
    const [type, setType] = useState("");
    const [modalOpen, setmodalOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setmodalOpen(false);
    
    const handleSave = () => {      
        axios
            .post("dshservices/api/Dataset/UploadFile", 'example data')
            .then((res) => {
                const { dateCreated, id, databaseName, schemaName, tableName } = res.data.value;

                setResponseMessage(`time of success: ${dateCreated}`);
                setType("success");
                setmodalOpen(true);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setResponseMessage(
                    `time of error: ${new Date().toLocaleDateString() + " (CST)*"}, ${error}`
                );
                setType("error");
                setmodalOpen(true);
            });
    };

    return (
        <Content>   
            <Button onClick={handleSave} disabled={disabled} variant="contained">
                UPLOAD FILE
            </Button>
                                            
            <ResponseModal
                message={responseMessage}
                type={type}
                handleClose={handleClose}
                open={modalOpen}
            />
        </Content>
    );
};
```

Comment: You need to wrap your 'handleSave' function in a 'useEffect' hook. The issue is that your component is not re-rendering

Comment: do you mean a useCallback? a useEffect gets called on a re-render when state changes depending on the dependency array. I believe it is re-rendering because if I console.log(modalOpen) inside of useEffect() it consoles true which tells me it is re-rendering. I will try to make handleSave a useCallback, maybe that will help